# Will splitting a tensed string by the ends and in the middle make the two long parts not go flying around?

Tags: forces, string

If you chop a guitar string with 3 swords at the exact same time:

`------------` to `-|-----|-----|-`

Would the 2 big parts not move at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The centers of mass of those two big parts would not move, assuming that the cutting could be done without imparting a force to the string.**  Conservation of momentum means that the center of mass will not be moving after the cut if it wasn't moving before the cut.

However, the strings would be contracting and possibly the ends would be whipping around.